# Is there an easy way to add multiple HTML pages to my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress

I've got ~100 static HTML pages and would like to add them to my WordPress site. They're simple HTML, with the only complicating factor being they're all linked together, so it would be best if they were all together under one directory. Will I have to do this one page at a time?

Thanks, as always!

Comment: May I ask what kind of content do these 100 page have? And do they share any kind of pattern within the content?

Comment: They're the help files for a software application I wrote. Each page has almost identical code, displaying simple navigation in one frame and text or image content in the other frame.

Comment: I see. You may have no choice but to copy the content and paste them in wordpress by hand. Unless you can build a page scrapper that can scrape the content off of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Import HTML Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-html-pages/) plugin should do what you want, without the pain of manually creating the pages one at a time.